# Acts as follower Set Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) working but i'm missing something. A user should be able to Follow another User.

I added the Gem :

```
gem "acts_as_follower", '~> 0.2.0' #0.2.0 for Rails 4
```

In my User model i added :

```
acts_as_follower
acts_as_followable
```

The User Controller i created looks like this :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

My routes :

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'screens#index'

  devise_for :users
  get 'u/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

  resources :screens, :path => 's' do
    member do
      get :like
      get :unlike
    end
  end


  get "pages/home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get "users/show"

end
```

now in the routes i have to add the member :follow =>

```
member do
  get :follow
end
```

But i'm stuck at this point. I tried a few variations and my link to follow a User is :

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user)%>
```

and this is giving me the error ->

```
undefined method `follow_users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb4da78e920>:0x007fb4db3facb8>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution was to create a `user resource`, it works perfectly now =>

```
resources :users do
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
```